# Convert a string into a list with integers including negative numbers

Tags: python, string, list

I want to convert this string

```
-1, -2, 3, 4, 5
```

into a list with those values.

```
[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When the values are positive, I have many options but I can't seem to get it once there is a "-" character involved.

If possible, I'd like not to use regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string = "-1, -2, 3, 4, 5"
print [int(el) for el in string.split(',')]
```

**output:**

```
[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is what I have been searching for the past 24 hours of my life?! thanks. It was so simple and right under my nose the whole time.

Comment: What if there are no spaces in the string? How to make `"-1-2345" ` output to `[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 3):

You can split it directly and then use map function to convert them to int as shown below:

```
arr = map(int,s.strip().split(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
s = '-1, -2, 3, 4, 5'
lst = [int(x.strip()) for x in s.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completness of this problem, here is a solution using [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> import ast
>>> list(ast.literal_eval("-1, -2, 3, 4, 5"))
[-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]
```