# How to convert Textinput text to a matrix

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am new to kivy/python. I wanted to test my programming skills, so I modified this code off a post. It take texts as numbers from the textinput and converts them into a matrix and performs an operation. It works perfectly for positive numbers, however I want to capture negative numbers as well. But that always gives an error.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint = (None, None))
        self.add_widget(self.input)
        self.input.bind(on_text_validate=self.print_input)

    def print_input(self, value):
        """function to convert Textinput text into a matrix"""

        ans1 = [i for i in list(value.text) if i != ',']
        new = []
        for i in range(len(ans1)):
            if ans1[i] == "-":
                n = ans1[i] + ans1[i + 1]  # concatenate "-" and the next item after it
                ans1.remove(ans1[i])      # delete "-"
                ans1.remove(ans1[i+1])    # delete the next element after "-"
                new.append(n)
             new.append(ans1[i])
         # the list new can now be converted into a matrix of which dimension depends on the list 
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
    return Screen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
if ans1[i] == "-":
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: please anyone here to help me out. I'm really struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! I have seen the magic. The secret was string.split()
This is the modified code. Works perfectly for both positive and 
negative entries.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from sympy import *

class Screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint = (None, None))
        self.add_widget(self.input)
        self.input.bind(on_text_validate=self.print_input)

    def print_input(self, value):
        """function to convert Textinput text into a matrix. works
        for only square matrices"""

        m = 3; n = 3  # rows and columns
        list = [float(el) for el in value.text.split(',')]  # entries must be separated with ','
        mat = Matrix(list)
        mat1 = mat.reshape(3, 3)  # can be made general
        pprint(mat1)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Screen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The secret was this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799209/convert-a-string-into-a-list-with-integers-including-negative-numbers)